# Decoding multiple sentences in tensorflow with respect to the sentence dependencies

Tags: nlp, tensorflow

the `decode` function in the `translate.py` file from the [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py) contains the line `model.batch_size = 1  # We decode one sentence at a time.`

In this example I want to decode not one, but three sentences:

1. This is todays MovieWorld cinema schedule.
2. Look for the special offers available for gold member.
3. After your visit, please return the 3D glasses.

Now, how can I make sure that the decoding function takes the dependencies among the sentences into account? I want the model to take sentence 1 into account, when decoding sentence 2 and 3.

Do I only have to change the `model.batch_size` or anything else as well?

Comment: batch_size is not what you are looking for. When you have multiple sentences in a batch they are processed at the same time but the result is the same as if they were done independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural translation models are usually trained to do one sentence at a time. That means that there would be little advantage in decoding the three sentences all together. If you wnat to do that though you can try concatenating them into a single string comprised of three sentences and then decoding it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I sticked with the original idea of translation models.